# Force template instantiation in another header

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a templated "collection" class. I don't wan't the code be recompiled in every source file. But this collection should be used with DataTypes (`class SpecialDataMember : DataMember`) not defined on definition of the the template class.
This is why I can't force the instantiation in the template source file (throug moving the definitions to the source file and add `template LinkCollection<DataMember>;`), because the definitions of the template must be accessible in other source files ("`SpecialDataMember.cpp`").

Is it possible to make "`SpecialDataMember.o`" hold the code for `LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>`. Every includer of `SpecialDataMember.h` should know I leave `LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>` to the linker.

I see two options but I don't know if they work:

1. Make two template headers (with header guard) one with the definitions one without.

SpecialDataMember.h

```
// ..
include "LinkCollection.h"
// ..
```

SpecialDataMember.cpp

```
// .. 
include "LinkCollectionImpl.h"
// .. 
include "SpecialDataMember.h"
// .. 
template LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>;
```

All includers of "`SpecialDataMember.h`" will not know the definitions of the template so they will let the linker do his work.And the linker will find the instantiation of `LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>` in `SpecialDataMember.o`. Is that correct?
But I would have to maintain two header Files. Is there a better way to gain this effect?

2. Use template derived classes

If I create a special `class SpecialDataMemberLinkCollection : LinkCollection<SpecialDataMemberLink>` in the "`SpecialDataMember`" header and source file, I could reference this special class instead and so the compiler knows there is an instantiation of that class and the base class template and leaves the work to the linker. Will this work as expect?

Comment: Why and how can I get the effect wanted?

Comment: I readed the "duplicate", the question is different and the answer doesn't help. I'm using the technic descriped in the answer in the first option. The difference is that I force the instanciation in another source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to make "SpecialDataMember.o" hold the code for `LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>`. Every includer of `SpecialDataMember.h` should know I leave `LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>` to the linker.

Simple, just put:

```
extern template class LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>;
```

in the header, which tells the compiler not to instantiate that template and leave it to another file.

Then in one `SpecialDataMember.cpp` file provide that instantiation:

```
template class LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>;
```

Comment: Will `template LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>;` work if `extern template LinkCollection<SpecialDataMember>;` is defined in the header?

Comment: Yes. Just like declaring a function and then defining it later works OK. The `extern template` one is an explicit instantation declaration that says "there will be an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program", but it doesn't say the definition can't come later in the same file.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, no, I just did a copy&paste from the question, which was missing it :) fixed now, thanks